# MySQL group by different values in same column

Tags: mysql

I want to group the output by year so that I have 2 rows. One row for count in 2019 and one row for count in 2020. Is it even possible? Is there a similar output variant?

Here's my code:

```
select count(*)
     , leirueck 
  from ausleihe 
 where leirueck between "2019-02-01" and "2019-02-10" 
    or leirueck between "2020-02-01" and "2020-02-10" 
 group  
    by leirueck
```

And here the output

```
count(*) leiruck
      17 2019-02-02
      37 2019-02-04
      16 2019-02-06
      20 2019-02-07
      21 2019-02-09
      47 2020-02-01
      17 2020-02-02
      57 2020-02-03
      37 2020-02-04
      16 2020-02-06
      20 2020-02-07
     105 2020-02-09
```

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Show us how do you want your output to look like.

Answer (score 0):

If you group by the year in the date fields using the mysql `year()` function

```
select count(*)
     , year(leirueck)
  from ausleihe 
 where leirueck between "2019-02-01" and "2019-02-10" 
    or leirueck between "2020-02-01" and "2020-02-10" 
 group  
    by year(leirueck)
```